# Twitter Bootstrap body background with CSS3 Animation

Tags: css, animation, twitter-bootstrap

So I ditched into CSS3 Animation these days, so I'm playing with it right now. But unfortunately, I have an issue in positioning the bg image to the bottom.

This is the code I'm working on:

```
  body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  background: #A9D0F5 url("../image/bg-clouds.png") repeat-x fixed center bottom;
  animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
  /*background-color: #008bcf;*/    
}

@-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { background-position: 0 0; }
        to { background-position: 100% 0; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { background-position: 0 0; }
        to { background-position: 100% 0; }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { background-position: 0 0; }
        to { background-position: 100% 0; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { background-position: 0 0; }
        to { background-position: 100% 0; }
    }
```

What seems to be the problem here? Any ideas? Thanks.

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rex2E/

Comment: why not throw a jsfiddle together to help us help you faster?

Comment: added one, please check.

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383438/keeping-background-image-at-bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for adding the Fiddle. I fiddled around with it and got the background to position itself on the bottom.

When you are setting 0 as the position value you are talking about to Top or the Left ... 0 0 is top left.

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/kJLTc/)

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 20px;
   color: #333333;
   background: #A9D0F5 url("http://i43.tinypic.com/fcmjv4.png") repeat-x fixed center bottom;
   animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
   -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
@-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: center bottom; }
  to { background-position: 100% bottom; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: center bottom; }
    to { background-position: 100% bottom; }
}
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: center bottom; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: center bottom; }
    to { background-position: 100% bottom; }
}
```

It's working for me in Chrome on PC, let me know if it works for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should set you background animation inside `div` and check this :

[Sticky footer and body background image at the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086421/sticky-footer-and-body-background-image-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

There are some answers that might help you